# Custom archive widget drop down menu

Tags: widgets, archives

need to display archive drop down as Jan-march 2017, April-June 2017 like that, is that possible

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I change the way dates shown in the archive widget?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/44905/how-can-i-change-the-way-dates-shown-in-the-archive-widget)

Comment: No, that not my requirement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [archives widget](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-includes/widgets/class-wp-widget-archives.php) uses the [`wp_get_archives`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_archives/) function to generate the dropdown list. As you can see from the source code, there is no native way to use other dropdowns than yearly/monthly/weekly/daily. Unfortunately, there also is no hook to insert your own quarterly dropdown. So, there is no easy way to do this.

There is a deeper problem, too: there is no native WP way to link to a bunch of posts by quarter as there is for years and months. This exists: `www.example.com\2017\05`. This doesn't: `www.example.com\2017\Q1`.

That doesn't mean it can't be done. But you're looking at [building your own archive dropdown widget](https://codex.wordpress.org/Widgets_API#Developing_Widgets) and combining it with a [smart date query](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Date_Parameters) to be able to link to a quarterly archive.